# How can I position an item vertically offset from the center such that the space around it shrinks to zero as the view port shrinks?

Tags: html, css

Here is an example of exaclty what I'm looking for, but I hate having to use elements just for padding. I was wondering if there's a way to do it without using extra elements.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh
}

#content {
  --size: 150px;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style='flex: 1;'></div>
  <div id='content'></div>
  <div style='flex: 3;'></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without extra element you can use pseudo element:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh
}

body:before {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
}

body:after {
  content: "";
  flex: 3;
}

#content {
  --size: 150px;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='content'></div>
</body>
```

Or you can use CSS grid:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows:1fr auto 3fr;
  height: 100vh
}

#content {
  --size: 150px;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  border: solid;
  grid-row:2;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='content'></div>
</body>
```

Another idea is to consider margin:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content {
  --size: 150px;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  border: solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin-top:calc((100vh - 150px)/4);
}

@media (max-height:150px) {
  #content {
    margin-top:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='content'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, I actually tired the grid way and it didn't work. I must have messed something up.